# How do I select an dom element in a cell based other strings found elsewhere in the tables row using jquery?

Tags: jquery, select, filter, compare, cell

I have a table that holds a status, product type, and radio selection to see if the user wants it selected or not.  If the user chooses "no" for any item I am trying to disable all the other radio buttons that are in a row with the same status and category.

The challenge is I am unable to find and select the radio buttons that match the criteria.  Here is the jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/LwPCv/

This is obviously an over simplification of what I'm really trying to do but this covers the basic concept.  Thanks so much!  Oh, I'm using jquery as well.

In my jsfiddle the test would be if the user chooses "no" on row 1, then the last row radio buttons would be disabled.

```
$(".runTest").click(function () {

    $("tr").each(function () {
        var curRow = $(this);
        var curStatus = curRow.find('td:first').text();
        var curRowAccepted = curRow.find('input:radio:checked').val();
        //if the current row is not selected find any other matching rows and deselect them;
        if (!curRowAccepted) {
            //trim the string and extract just the category from a full string;
            var curRowCategory = findCategory(curRow.find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
            var charAtSplit = curRowCategory.indexOf("-");
            curRowCategory = curRowCategory.substr(0, charAtSplit);
            curRowCategory = $.trim(curRowCategory);

            //I need to disable all other radio buttons that match the Status and Category
            $('input:radio').filter($('tr:contains(curRowCategory))').filter($('tr:contains(curStatus))')).disable();
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: This is the row I need help on... $('input:radio').filter($('tr:contains(curRowCategory))').filter($('tr:contains(curStatus))')).disable();

Comment: I have also tried this approach to no avail  http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/LwPCv/

Comment: Why does the jsFiddle not have any of the code you've posted here? I'm not clear what your question is.